# implementing I/O file(s) redirections + pipes

Tags: c, shell, unix, io, io-redirection

I'm writing a shell for school assignment !
I have figured it out how to implement redirections like that.

```
ls | cat | wc
```

My question is how can i combine piping + files redirection like :

```
ls | cat < input1 < input2 > output | wc
```

The only way i see to make this working is to create sub processes whith intermediates pipes (tees). Am i right or there is an easier way ?

Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english !

Comment: What do you expect `ls | cat < input1 < input2 > output | wc` to do?

Comment: @jxh cat inputs: ls and input1 and input2      cat outputs: output and wc. You can try in any shell.

Comment: I don't think it does what you think it does. There is only one stdin, but you are initializing it 3 times. Only one of them will actually stick. There is only one stdout, but you are trying to use it twice. Only one will actually stick.

Comment: You can't do that trivially even in shell. The closest thing to this would be something like `cat <(ls ; cat input1 input2) | (tee output | wc -l)` (using subshell and process substitution from bash)

Comment: @jxh Well it's work for me in zsh. `ls | cat < anyfile < anyfile` cat will print ls result and the file twice.

Comment: Okay it's not working in bash. I will allow only one input and one output then. Will be much easier ;) Thank you.